# regex - preg_replace string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i want to replace a string's non-alphanumeric characters into space.

i used 
`$title= preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", " ", $title);`

so when users inputs

> abc!?d$

it will be

> abc d

but beacuse user input it to a text-input it goes to "x.php?title=abc!?d$".
i want it to go to "x.php?title=abc+d"
because i want "abc d", "abc$$$$$$$$$d", "abc__.!d" etc. to go to same url.
how can i manage this. thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, what you're saying is that if there are more than one replacable characters next to each other, then you only want to put one space character there. Is that right?

In that case, yes, it's easy: you simply need to add a plus sign after the character class in the regex, like so:

```
$title = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/", " ", $title);
```

The plus sign tells regex to look for one or more match of the preceding item.

Hope that helps.

Comment: in Javascript, you need the `g` modifier after your regex. PHP doesn't seem to need it in `preg_replace()`; the answer given replaces all occurrences. If you're just doing matching, PHP has two functions: `preg_match()` and `preg_match_all()`.

Comment: Thanks @Spudley. That response would have made sense If I hadn't deleted my comments! Out of interest, would the approach in my answer below also work in PHP. (I.e. using `\W` instead of  `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/`). I'm trying to learn Regex, and part of that is understanding the differences between the dialects.

Comment: @James: `\W` is close, but wouldn't be correct for this specific case because it includes underscores, which the OP doesn't want.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid off unwanted characters use following code:

```
$_GET['title'] = 'abc__.!d';

$title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/', ' ', $_GET['title']); // "abc d"
```

Now, just redirect to correct URL (if needed)

```
if ($_GET['title'] != $title) {
    header('Location: ....');
    die('Redirect to ...URL...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `\W` switch for matching non-aplha chars? (In conjunction with the `+`)

```
$title= preg_replace(/\W+/g, " ", $title);
```

(In JavaScript you also need the `/g` flag as well, not sure if this is true for PHP)

EDIT:

The requirement states that all `_` should be eliminated, so the following would work.

```
(\W|_)+
```

However, probably best to stipulate the exact chars you want in this instance, rather than trying to build up an exclude list, as my asnwer is starting to do.

Comment: As it turns out, this wouldn't work because underscore inclusion is a requirement. Thought I'd leave it for posterity, though, as I think its still relevant.