# Regex and JavaScript String With a Dollar ($) at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

In answering this PHP question: [regex - preg_replace string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6411119/144491), I came across something in Javascript I didn't understand.
Given the following:

```
var s = "abc1!?d$";
alert(s.replace(/\W+/, " "));
```

I am alerted:

```
abc d$
```

Why is it not stripping out the last dollar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because there's an intervening word character. Try this:

```
alert(s.replace(/\W+/g, ' '));
```

Without the "g" suffix on the regex, it only makes one substitution. That handles the "!?" in the middle, but that "d" ends the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not using the (g)lobal flag on your matcher, so it's only matching the first *consecutive sequence* of non-word characters.

The following should give the result you expect:

```
var s = "abc1!?d$";
alert(s.replace(/\W+/g, " "));
```